# Asking for a grocery in russian

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I wanted to walk into a russian grocery store (there is one in my neighborhood) and ask if they sell квас.

What is a good approach when walking into a small store and asking for something?

Would: Добрый день or Здравствуйте be more suitable?

Followed by:
Скажите пожалуйста, Вы продаете квас?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would: Добрый день or Здравствуйте be more suitable?

Well, both OK, except sometimes people may also omit any greeting, as this is not a true "personal" communication.

> Followed by: Скажите пожалуйста, Вы продаете квас?

Better to say: Скажите, пожалуйста, *у вас есть* квас?

Note that you may omit "Скажите, пожалуйста" too, yet in any case you should keep at least one "polite" phrase per speech, e.g.: "Добрый день! У вас есть квас?" is OK, but the sole "У вас есть квас?" may sound impolite.

Comment: Do you normally drink квас cold (chilled) or as is?

Comment: @Дженни They say квас is a sort of beer. Do you know anyone who prefer the warm beer? :-) Maybe only in "окрошка" it would do. Otherwise chilled one, yet don't get a cold. And homemade квас is far much better than any industrial stuff.

Answer (score 0):

**Здравствуйте** is a time independent greeting, while **Добрый день** literally means "good day", and fit more for daylight time. Also, you can say just "здрАсти".

Asking about some goods the easiest way is to say "**У вас есть**...?", meaning "Do you have... ?"

Example dialogue:

- Здрасти! У вас есть квас?
- Конечно, сколько вам кваса?
- Два литра, пожалуйста.
- С вас 100 рублей.